# Getting next value out of list when reacting to an event in F#

Tags: events, f#

I have an F# program that generates a list of states.  I also have a windows form which uses GDI+ to render graphics that represent the state to the screen.  When the user click a button in the form the next state should be rendered.  In C# I would store an index and use this to get the next state out of the list.  I know I could create a mutable variable and do the same thing in F#, but that doesn't seem like the right way to do it.

Is there a way that better fits into the functional programming paradigm to get the next value out of a list when an event is fired? pseudo-code for the click event:

```
let clicked e =
    let state = getNextState
    render state
```

Comment: Actually the button click will invalidate the panel, and the paint even will do the getting of the next state and rendering, but I wanted to keep the example's logic simple.

Comment: you should also explore [Gjallarhorn](http://reedcopsey.github.io/Gjallarhorn/index.html) which is quite great for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In practice, I think that using a mutable variable is perfectly fine - using a single mutable variable to keep the current state is quite common pattern in F#.

That said, you can encode the logic using the `Event.scan` function. The function keeps state and lets you calculate a new state every time an event happens. Here is a minimal demo that uses this to create a button with a number on it that gets incremented every time you click:

```
let frm = Form(Visible=true)
let btn = Button(Text="Click")
frm.Controls.Add(btn)
```

As in your example, we have some initial state, function to calculate the next state and a function that updates the GUI based on the current state:

```
let initialState = 0
let nextState state = state + 1
let updateForm state = btn.Text <- string state
```

Now you can use `Event.scan` to create a new event that contains the "current state" calculated by applying `nextState` to the previous state on each click. Using `Event.add`, we then call `updateForm` when the state changes:

```
btn.Click 
|> Event.scan (fun oldState event -> nextState oldState) initialState
|> Event.add (fun state -> updateForm state)
```